# Rise again of Vijayanagara Empire after fall

Tags: history

The mighty Hindu kingdom declined and could not easily rise up in a short time to its former glory.. in the absence of its founder king.

Why no restorative forces automatically entered into action in its quick revival?

At the behest of a single ruling British commander Indian majority Hindu followers opened fire killing fellow Hindu believers at Jalianwala bag...all for an employee's salary?

Nationalistic revolutionary movement for Indian independence spanned coolly laid back from 1857 to 1947, a good part of one century.

Is there something in the faith that accepts defeat and subjugation for too long.. as a needed survival philosophy?.. in spite of BG's extortion to self-defend against injustice..?

If so what advises are given in olden times .. Manu Smriti, Kautilya Neethi etc..to observe restraint and under which circumstances should one agree to lie low?